# Cheapest way to wirelessly synchronize two MCUs

Tags: microcontroller, rf, wireless

I have two battery powered MCUs about 30cm apart, one will be the master, and one the slave. Each MCU has several LEDs connected which flash in a sequence.

All I want to do is synchronize the two MCUs so that the sequences don't drift out of phase.

Is there some super easy way to send a simple RF pulse from one MCU to the other?

Added:

- The sequence lasts for approx 1 second, and repeats forever.
- If the slave misses some sync pulses, it's not the end of the world, because it would take many cycles to drift noticeably out of phase.
- For personal / religious / aesthetic reasons which I am not allowed to discuss, I do not wish to use IR, capacitive, acoustic means to transmit this pulse.
- The range is very short, less than 30cm.
- The signal will need to travel through open air. No concrete or metal in the way.
- RF-like inductive coupling would be OK too.
- Since the signal consists of only a single pulse, I imagine there must be a smaller, cheaper solution than those involving packet transmission (Xbee, etc.)
- Ideally the solution would consist of some kind of PCB trace antenna, and a simple oscillator for the transmitter, and simple circuit (demodulator?) to detect the pulse at the receiver.

Comment: A better decription of your environment would save everyone time and improve answer quality. There are many "obvious" solutions that may not be suitable BUT as you do not explain your al need nobody can tell*. 
Please explain why RF not suited. NFC may suffice - electromagnetic RF **LIKE** coupling. Optical may work. Acoustic may work.  You do not mention wire connection. Is this unsuitable - if so, say why, as that is the most obvious and easiest method. [[* eg potted in concrete, welsed in  a mumetal drum at the bottom of a shallow shark pond ... :-) ]]

Comment: Unteachable. Intractable. Declines to accept sage advice. D- fail. Bzzzzt. Next please.

Comment: If given reasons for rejecting IR are the only relevant ones then IR **MAY** be best. Details withheld, but if orientation is continuously randomly variable a single IR TX-RX pair will orient often enough to exchange sync codes. A randomly oriented continuous variable posn TX and RX will achieve adequate linkage asymptoting to about 1/(Pi^2) of the time or about 10%. Sync hold time depends on clk stab etc but is easily minutes +. Worst case, multiple IR tx and rx units will always provide linkage from ANY orientation and may still be cheapest & easiest option. Note: 1 x LED can be IR RX & TX.

Comment: @Russell, if you're determined not to answer the question, then just say nothing.

Comment: Tha's pretty rude. Do you not see my extensive and apposite answer with fully fleshed RF solution. Is that not what you asked for?

Comment: @Russell, so is "Unteachable. Intractable." You are basically saying that I am too stupid to know my own requirements.

Comment: Russell, would you mind if we took this to meta? I think there are some fundamental questions to resolve about how we ask and answer questions.

Comment: @RM - You asked for an RF or other solution. I provided one possible RF solutions in vast detail + suggestions re searching for others. You have not commented on or shown any sign of having seen my RF solution but keep asking for an RF solution. You say an IR solution will not work but given what you have told me I could have build an IR solution with ease. You say you have disclosed all data relevant to an IR solution and also say it cannot be done. I know [tm] that your statement set as a whole is logically inconsistent, and you are asking for an RF solution but ignoring the one given.

Comment: So -  serious question - How would you summarise the situation from my viewpoint. What have I got wrong. Why can't you see my RF solution? Why do you keep asking for one when there is one laid out in vast detail - even if just to say it doesn't suit, and why. When I, afer too many decades playing this game **KNOW** I could make IR work given your spec, why do yu say I am wrong, and on what grounds? You say I refuse to answer your question but you seem to be refusing to read my answer. How can I do better? Really?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2899/discussion-between-rocketmagnet-and-russell-mcmahon)

Comment: We seem to have stalled on this. If you are happy with what you got that's fine. If you want better answers the ball's in your court, as it were. Simpler than shown is easy enough. Easier than shown is not so easy :-).

Comment: I thought we were chatting in that chat place ? I'd really like to clear up what we mean by good and bad questions and answers, and leave things on a friendly note.

Comment: I answer many many many questions. I try to do as well as I can in each case. In this instance my so far (here) unacknowledged answer fully addresses your stated requirement. I see no reason why this cannot be refined if it does not suit you for reasons so far (here) unspecified. Technical comments in chat do not help people see the progression of the question and answer. Best way to talk to me about other matters is probably email as chat has large 'ships in the night" factor. My email address is on my profile page. (The guardians of the sacred protocols do not allow me to post it here).

Comment: I just realized this place is just way too generous for impatient ppl, you are here to seek answers from experienced engineers, at least trying to be humble when ppl are trying to offer help? "Do you guys need to have my whole life story before answering the question?" , right, I would probably just leave the post and never answer it even if I know the answer to it. I hope after 12 years you did pick up one or two.

Answer (score 9):

The application **SOUNDS** so trivially simple that, if it isn't, there is no way to know due to the "death by 1,000 blows" approach to defining the problem.  At 30 cm the way to use RF is to use RF. Any RF equipment that I have ever met would work over that range in free air in the absence of metal. You can buy transceivers and transmitter / receiver pairs. With the stated specs, if it transmits and receives RF it will be suitable. If any RF data transfer solution does not work in this context then it is because the spec is inadequate. Simple RF solutions usually have minimal latency once the data stream is synchronised. All that is required is Sync_phase - delay_until - sync_now. QED. Repeat as needed. Processor helps BUT a cheap no processor solution is easy.

More complex RF systems such as Bluetooth will also work but may have variable latency. This can be overcome by some interactive communications that establishes link parameters OR designed around known performance. BUT simple cheap off the shelf one way RF modules will work well enough. "ASK" transmission is probably fine and gives you something to search for.

[This $5 receiver {315 MHz version}](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10533)  or [434 MHz version](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10532)

[image]

plus this [$4 transmitter](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10535) or [its up frequency  cousin](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10534)

[image]

will together give you a $9 solution if you are happy to talk one way.
  Double that for 2 way.

Or

[Two of these $7 transceivers - 434 MHz](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/9582)  will give you a bidirectional $14 solution. ~ 16mm x 16mm x 4.2mm.
   That size is known OK as the spec did not specifiy otherwise when all details were provided.
 That cost is known OK as the spec did not specifiy otherwise when all details were provided.

[image]

[Datasheet](http://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Wireless/General/RFM12B.pdf)
 [Programming guide](http://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Wireless/General/RF12B_code.pdf)
 [eXCELLENT APPLICATION GUIDE](http://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Wireless/General/RF12B-IC.pdf)
 [mORE OF THE SAME - MANUFACTURERS HOME PAGE {PROBABLY}](http://www.hoperf.com/pro/rf/cob/RFM12B.htm)
 [rfm12 LIBRARY](http://www.das-labor.org/wiki/RFM12_library/en)

---

[Two of these give you a WiFi link](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10808) - over over over kill.

---

- **BUT**

In the absence of any real clues as to why the following are not suitable, the following may be suitable:

- IR **may** work well and easily and cheaply.
  **Unless you are an IR expert,  your reasons for excluding it may well be unsound.**
  With what you have told us so far, IR would be the candidate solution of choice.
  Low cost, easy, low power.  ie
  **Better, cheaper, faster - choose any three!**
  Tell us what you want and we'll tell you what you need :-)
- Electromagnetic "**RF LIKE**" "near field" coupling may or may not suit better than RF. .
- Optical
- Acoustic
- Capacitive
- ...  GSM ... Iridium ... Inmarsat ... [just joking] :-) .

Pleased explain clearly & completely the environment and relevant constraints. eg:
 Potted in concrete, welded in  a mumetal drum at the bottom of a shallow shark pond ... :-).
 Indoors, outdoors, ... .

There are many "obvious" solutions that may or may be suitable BUT as you do not explain your real need nobody can tell*.

Again: **Tell us what you want and we'll tell you what you need :-)**

IR sounds good to me, so far.

Comment: Er, what? I didn't say that I excluded RF. I said I ruled out IR. Why can't you just trust me that I'm sure RF is the way to go?

Comment: I did not mention a wire connection, but I did clearly say WIRELESS.

Comment: You didn't mention GSM modules or Iridium modems. -1 :)

Comment: @Rocketmagnet: I agree with Russell that you haven't really given a good reason for why non RF methods are inappropriate. Part of the purpose of this site is to make sure you're asking the right question and getting the right answer, not just to get a random answer.

Comment: Do you guys need to have my whole life story before answering the question? Is it too much to assume that I have already considered the various other options, and would have done something easier like IR if it was appropriate?

Comment: The question now contains an explanation why IR is not appropriate.

Comment: @Rocketmagnet what about all the rest???

Comment: With data provided so far I could make IR work fine. The only reason IR would not work would be if there was some relevant information not disclosed. Whether IR is the best solution is TBD as there is not enough data to know. As for answering the question. I suggest heeding the one time motto of the [Clackmananshire County Council](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clackmannanshire)  - "Look aboot ye" - or just above these comments in this case. Why have you not commented on that answer and instead asked for more? | Clue: **RF SOLUTION DETAILED ABOVE.**

Comment: @Rocket: Yes, it is too much to assume that you have considered all the options.  We don't know your competence level and of course have no idea what you think *all the options* includes.  Often enough the right answer to a question here is to go back and think about the problem differently.  If you knew all the answers, you wouldn't be here asking.  Your judgement of supposed implementation is of no relevance here since your competency has not been established yet.  If you are getting answers that you don't like but meet the requirements, then you provided incomplete requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide information on your budget constraints (power consumption, cost of parts, cost of your time, or hard time constraints (such as, I have one week to make this work))

Many of the RF modules listed have reviews posted about noise problems, which will require more software development or systems integration work to filter out the noise and end up with a usable signal

In addition to the RF modules listed above, there are Zigbee modules in the $20 price range available from several sources.  They have the advantage of having a standard interface, and ZigBee was intended to be used in "sensor networks" and other systems with low power availability (you mentioned battery power).

If you are already Arduino-friendly, there are some time savings to be had with a Zigbee/Xbee setup.

Good luck!

Comment: There is no deadline, but I would rather not spend 1 year tuning the system to make it work. I am aware of things like Zigbee, but since my application requires no data to be transmitted, I was hoping there would be an even simpler, cheaper, smaller solution.

Comment: @Rocketmagnet smaller than the 3rd picture is hard...give a look to Jennic, it's embedded micro+RF and has a very simple interface

Comment: @The Programmer -  At a range of 300mm, and needed time to deliver one time coordinated data bit of hours, I think the modules listed are up to the job [tm].  Modules that HAVE formal protocols are at a disadvantage here - BUT see the documentation I referenced.